# Is there a way to print out the type of a variable/pointer in C?

Tags: c, types

I want to print out (or otherwise ascertain) the type of some variable in my program.  Is there a good way to do it?  By good, I mean a way that works, even if it means intentionally throwing compiler errors.

For example:

```
client.c:55: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

is the error I'm getting right now.  What I WANT is it to tell me something like:

```
client.c:55: error: attempting to assign type struct a to type struct b
```

or a function that I can use like so:

```
printf(gettype(x));
```

which would output:

```
struct b
```

Comment: how can it "work" if it doesnt compile ?

Comment: If it "throws compiler errors", how can it work?

Comment: What I mean by "work" is it gives me the type so I can fix the error in my program.  See the edit.

Comment: Some compilers allow a verbosity setting - try that. Otherwise just look at the code. A decent IDE will usually automatically look up the types of variables so you can see the type by hovering or right clicking on the variable name.

Comment: To increase verbosity level, give -Wall -pedantic options to your gcc compiler. This should give you some additional info about your errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try debugging using GDB, it will print all properties associated with the variable including it's type. But, your program should compile before using GDB.

Comment: If it's failing to build you can't do this

Answer (score 84):

I have just discovered how to do this.

```
printf("%d", variable);
```

If variable is not an int then `gcc -Wall` will complain that the types don't match - and will print out the type of the variable, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Useful when you're in an environment where you don't know where to look stuff up (for example, in my situation, programming with yacc).

Comment: This is misleading when using array types that decay into pointers while being passed to `printf`.

Answer (score 5):

If you debug with `gdb`.
Then you can set a breakpoint with:
`break line_number` to break execution where you want to fetch that variable type.
And from then you can print the type of a variable in gdb with:
`ptype your_variable_name`
or
`whatis your_variable_name`
The last one will print the type of the variable as well as the definition you gave it.

Answer (score 3):

In C you provide a type when you declare a variable. That is the only information that the compiler has when it is complaining about the assignment (that is, it will not use the runtime type of the object, but the static type you have).

Go to the code, locate line 55, check what variables are there and find the types in the code. In C there are not even overloads, types are as static and simple as it gets in any language.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gcc or a gcc-compatible compiler then you can use the (obviously non-standard and non-portable) [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) keyword, which works much like sizeof.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get a string out of `typeof`. (Though on g++ you can use `typeid(typeof(x)).name()`.)

Comment: Since C11, you can also use `_Generic` to [to get the variable's type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290414/975097).