# Is introspection on a function's arguments in C possible?

Tags: c, function, arguments, introspection

For example, in Python I can use `getargspec` from `inspect` to access a function's arguments in the follow way:

```
>>> def test(a,b,c):
...     return a*b*c
...
>>> getargspec(test)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Is this possible to do in C at all? More specifically I am only interested in the arguments' names, I don't particularly care about their types.

Comment: AFAIK C doesn't contain any runtime information on this sort of stuff so no.

Comment: `C` has no support for this directly. You may be able to find a library that tries to hack it into the language, but it's likely going to be very ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language doesn't include anything along this line at all.

Depending on the implementation, there's a pretty fair chance that if you want this badly enough, you *can* get at it. To do so, you'll typically have to compile with debugging information enabled, and use code specific to a precise combination of compiler and platform to do it. Most compilers do support creating and accessing debugging information that would include the names of the parameters to a function -- but code to do it will not be portable (and in many cases, it'll also be pretty ugly).

Comment: I suppose it could be done, but it would be far to messy for my taste. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, all variable names are gone during compilation (except perhaps file-scope variables with "extern" storage duration), so you can't get the declaration names of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is absolutely impossible in C, since variable names exist only at compile time.

Probably it would be solvable via macro.
You could define

```
#define defFunc3(resultType,name,type0,arg0name,type1,arg1name,type2,arg2name) \
...store the variable names somehow... \
...you can access the variable name strings with the # operator, e.g. #arg0name \
...or build a function with concatenation: getargspec_##name \
resultType name(type0 arg0name, type1 arg1name, type2 arg2name )
```

and then declare your function with this macro:

```
defFunc3( float, test, float, a, float, b, float, c ) {
  return a * b * c;
}
```

In the macro body, you could somehow store the variable names (with the stringification preprocessor operator) and/or the function address somewhere or create some kind of "getargspec" function (via the concatenation preprocessor operator).

But this will be definitely ugly, error prone and tricky (since you can not execute code in such a function definition directly). I would avoid such macro magic whenever possible.

Comment: You can also use `_Generic` to [get the types of the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290414/975097) that are passed to the function.