# When writing a macro in C, how do I find the type and printf specifier for an argument?

Tags: c, macros, types, printf

I want to extend minunit to be more useful, with the macro.

```
#define mu_assert_equal(actual, expected) do {                                            \
  if (actual != expected) {                                                               \
    char *message = malloc(MAX_ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH);                                     \
    if (message == NULL) { printf("malloc failed"); exit(1); }                            \
    snprintf(message, MAX_ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH, "required: %s != %s, reality: %s == %lu", \
    #actual, #expected, #actual, actual);                                                 \
    return message;                                                                       \
  }                                                                                       \
} while (0)
```

invoked with:

```
mu_assert_equal(bytes_parsed, 1);
```

but the macro above only works for unsigned long values.

How I can I find the type of the macro arguments, and more importantly, their printf specifiers.

Comment: this is possible with C11 generics; not possible in C99 or older

Comment: For the C11 generic solution see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17290414/1505939), but change the descriptive strings to be the appropriate format specifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, in C before C11 (which adds [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)).

There's no way to compute the type of an expression in C, which is what you would need to do. If it were possible, then `printf()` wouldn't *need* to have static specifiers in the first place, more or less.

Comment: Thanks, there's a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981317/how-to-make-a-macro-return-characters-rather-than-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Without generics, perhaps the best would be different macros for your different types:

```
#define mu_assert_equal(actual, expected, test, fmt) do {                                 \
  if ( test ) {                                                                           \
    char *message = malloc(MAX_ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH);                                     \
    if (message == NULL) { printf("malloc failed"); exit(1); }                            \
    snprintf(message, MAX_ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH, "required: %s != %s, reality: %s == " fmt,\
    #actual, #expected, #actual, actual);                                                 \
    return message;                                                                       \
  }                                                                                       \
} while (0)

#define mu_assert_equal_int(actual, expected) \
        mu_assert_equal(actual, expected, actual != expected, "%lu")
#define mu_assert_equal_str(actual, expected) \
        mu_assert_equal(actual, expected, strcmp( actual, expected ), "%s")
```

and invoke as:

```
mu_assert_equal_str( test_str, "abcde" ) ;
mu_assert_equal_int( test_int, 12345 ) ;
```

(Edited in light of comment to also pass the test to the "generic" test).

Comment: `mu_assert_equal_str` has a bug - it just compares the memory addresses of strings - whereas what is usually needed is a strcmp/strncmp to compare their content.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was focusing on not having to duplicate the whole macro several times.  Will update.