# How to define general function to take input in C using _Generic?

Tags: c, generics, gcc, c11

I was trying to define a general function to take input using _Generic in C, This is what I wrote

```
#include  <stdio.h>

#define readlong(x) scanf("%lld",&x);
#define read(x) scanf("%lld",&x);

#define scan(x) _Generic((x), \
long long: readlong, \
default: read \
)(x)
```

but when I compile it using `gcc test.c -std=C11` on gcc 5.3.0,  I get error:

```
error: 'readlong' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11) help ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I already read that one.

Comment: Remove `;` after `#define` lines.

Comment: @n.m. It doesn't matter

Comment: Of course it does. You don't want semicolons in the middle of your macro expansion. Remove them *and* fix what rgon91 says. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01d13ed315318863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your helpers to be functions instead of macros. I modified `scan` so that it would pass the address to the matched function.

```
static inline int readlong (long long *x) { return scanf("%lld", x); }
static inline int readshort (short *x) { return scanf("%hd", x); }
static inline int unknown (void) { return 0; }

#define scan(x) _Generic((x), \
long long: readlong, \
short: readshort, \
default: unknown \
)(&x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
readlong
```

is not the variable that you have declared.  In:

```
#define readlong(x) scanf("%11d",&x);
```

you added (x).  This will not let you use readlong without them.

Comment: I already tried changing  `readlong` to `readlong(x)` but in that case I got error: `error: called object is not a function or function pointer
 #define scan(x) _Generic((x), \`