# C data type to store double or long or any other data

Tags: c, types

I want to create c struct that can hold 3 words of 'data'.

```
struct _Obj {
    ??? a;
    ??? b;
    ??? c;
}
typedef struct _Obj Obj;
```

But, I want to be able to store different types of data in a, b and c and cast them when needed appropriately.

For example, sometimes 'a' may be a long, other times it'll be a double and still others a pointer.  Runtime I will know what is stored in them, so I will want to be able to compile time (instantly) cast them to their datatype when needed.

```
Obj obj;
long a = 893;
obj.a = a;
double b = 3.14159;
obj.b = b;

long newA = (long)obj.a;
double newB = (double)obj.b;
```

Basically, I just want to be able to store some bits and then interpret them in a specific fashion later.  How do I do this?

Comment: You could use a union inside your struct with all the data types that you would like to support.

Comment: I'd say just make a `char` array of appropriate size or a `union`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wouldn't go with a `char` array. It provides virtually no type-safety and you might violate the strict-aliasing rule without careful usage.

Comment: @Downvoter Yep, it's not the best option. I'd use it only if the struct has to work with *any* type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union:

```
union {
    long integer;
    double floating_point;
    void *pointer;
} obj;
```

You don't need casting here and it's more type-safe than casting. Furthermore, casting isn't necessarily a runtime no-op (on little-endian, probably, but otherwise not), so a union really is your best bet if you want zero casting overhead.

In case you ever want types determined at compile-time, there's also the [`_Generic` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11) since C11.

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly, what I was looking for and very helpful.  (Thanks to Stamatic Liatsos and HolyBlackCat also)

Answer (score 0):

C allows bit reinterpretation.

Just define a binary format for your data, and extract. You can extract floating point types portably, but that's probably overkill here. Probably we can say that the longest datum we will need is the 80 bit double. So 30 bytes should be sufficient, plus two bytes to say what type the data is. So 32 bytes is a nice round power of two number.

Comment: C has better features for type-safety. C *allows* reinterpretation of data, doesn't mean you should (ab)use it. C++ introduced other casting mechanisms to replace C-style casting for a reason. Also, without the proper amount of carefulness, you might run into problems with strict-aliasing.

Comment: Type safety is very much over-rated. It's easy for the compiler to do which is why current languages have it. Bit-based programming where you say what the bits are and what they mean is more portable, simpler,doesn't break if the type system changes, and is safe - if you interpret a bit buffer with the wrong format you will almost certainly catch the bug on the first test.

Comment: I don't want to dive into a debate all too deeply here, but I don't see your point. C provides standard types, which have implementation-defined, undefined, and unspecified representations and behaviors. Using those types is portable because they are defined directly by the abstract machine C code is written for. Also, a C compiler knows about types and unions and emulating their properties, as does your suggested solution, may induce runtime overhead. Finally, if you're programming against a certain ABI you know, a certain architecture -- you might be right. But if it's in C, I disagree.

Comment: (cont.) (much to say here ^^) You talk about the possibility of the type system changing -- I mean, isn't that what a programming language is supposed to guarantee? C++ has relics from C for backwards compatibility; the comittee has decided against removing features because they wanted to preserve behavior of old C++ code bases. Type systems just don't break that easily. C is portable because you have an abstract machine, something independent of the actual implementation. If you're writing assembly, I completely agree with all you say. But then again, assembly doesn't have types like C has.

Comment: "[...] which have implementation-defined, undefined, and unspecified representations and behaviors [...]" *when fiddling with bits and bytes*, of course.