# Typecheck with Macro

Tags: c, types, macros, c11

I found this code and I understand what it does (prints if var is type of *float*) but I can't understand how:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define typename(x) _Generic((x), float: "float")

#define isCompatible(x, type) _Generic(x, type: true, default: false)

int main(){
  float var; 
  if(isCompatible(var, float))
    printf("var is of type float!\n");
}
```

What is **typename(x)**? Why is never called?
Also I can't understand this construct:

```
_Generic(x, type: true, default: false)
```

And here is there a way to not pass *float* as parameter and make it implicit?

```
if(isCompatible(var, float))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it implicit"? That would seem to defeat the point.

Comment: And you should read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

Comment: @interjay I mean, if i always want to know if a data is type of float, i think it's not necessary to pass **float** as parameter and define the macro in another way.

Comment: If you want to know if a variable is compatible with type T, obviously you would need to tell the compiler what T is. If you just want a `IsCompatibleWithFloat` macro that only works with `float`, you can just hardcode `float` in there instead of making it a parameter.

Comment: @interjay It's exactly what i'd like to do but what do you mean with "hardcore float in there"?

Comment: Remove the `type` parameter and write `float` instead of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want to look at the documentation for `_Generic` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) - it's a C11 feature *(C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) s 6.5.1.1 Generic selection (p: 78-79))*. See also the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

In essence in this example, the `isCompatible` macro calls `_Generic` and (via `type: true`) returns `true` if `x` (the first argument) is compatible with type `type`, else `false`.

The macro `typename` is not used, but returns the text `float` if the the argument is compatible with `float`. For why there is something defined but not used you would have to ask the author of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why `typename` is never called is a question you should ask the developper of the code snippet...

The `_Generic` keyword is a C11 feature.
The idea is to generate different code depending of the type of a variable.

C does not have a `typeof` operator like Java, thus what in Java looks like

```
...
if(typeof(p) == typeof(double)) {
    System.out.println("Got type 1");
} 
if(typeof(p) == typeof(char)) {
     System.out.println("Got type 2");
}
...
```

can be achieved through `_Generic` in C11 via

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_MY_TYPE_NUMBER(x) _Generic((x), \
    double: printf("Got type 1\n"),\
    char: printf("Got type 2\n") \
)

int main(int c, char** v) {

    double p = 10;

    PRINT_MY_TYPE_NUMBER(p));

}
```

*Note*: `_Generic` does not support arbitrary, but only 'simple' types.

The idea behind `isCompatible(variable, type)` is to return `true` if `variable` has a type compatible to `type`. It depends on `type` being passed over, and therefore its depends `type` being passed, making `type` implicitly passed over renders the `isCompatible` useless IMHO.