# Example of using the ## preprocessor operator

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know the following is a very trivial example, but how would I convert the following into a single function call that uses the preprocessor `##` 'glue' operator?

```
void print_string(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
void print_num(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_string("Hello");
    print_num(5);
}
```

The only thing I can thing of (which doesn't really simplify anything) is:

```
#define PRINT(type) print_ ## type
PRINT(string)("Hello");
PRINT(num)(4);
```

Or, is there a better way to use that?

Comment: Try _Generic from C11?

Comment: @tstanisl thanks, could you show an example please? I've never used that type(?) before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9804371/4989451

Comment: You can't do this with the preprocessor. The preprocessor deals with compile-time values, not run-time values.

Comment: You can do this with the preprocessor, just not with precisely the syntax you show. Would you accept a syntax requiring `PRINT(string, "Hello");` instead of `PRINT(string)("Hello");` ?

Comment: @Yunnosch sure that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the identification to be the first function argument:

```
#define PRINT(type, value)   print_ ## type(value)
PRINT(string, "Hello");
PRINT(num, 4);
```

But I see no value in that over just writing `printf`, as someone will have to learn to write `num` in case of `int`, he might as well learn to use `%d` anyway:

```
printf("%s\n", "Hello");
printf("%d\n", 4);
```

Type dispatch is not possible in **pre**-processor - it's not aware of types. In C11 there's `_Generic` that allows compiler to choose different function depending on type:

```
#define PRINT(value) _Generic((value), \
        char *: print_string, \
        int: print_int)(value)
PRINT("Hello");
PRINT(4);
```

By overloading the macro on each argument and applying such `_Generic` macro on each argument it's possible to build a replacement for C++ `std::cout`. So a little self-promotion: that's a topic I explored in [yio library](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/) that allows just to do:

```
yprint("Hello ", 4, "\n");
```