# How to find if the data type is a struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

Assume that you have the struct `my_struct` in C.
Then you are using `sizeof(my_struct)` to find how many bytes that struct have. Is there any way to find out that `my_struct` is a struct just by using `sizeof()` method in C?

For example, if I want to find out that `my_variable` is `16-bit`, then I just check if `sizeof(my_variable) == 2`.

Can I do the same for struct in C?

Comment: Certainly not, because it's possible to have a struct whose size is, say, 2.

Comment: No. Why would you even want to do that? It is your code and you know what the type is.

Comment: If such an introspection feature did exist, `sizeof` wouldn't be the place for it (How is "is this a struct?" related to the question of "how big is this thing in bytes?"). I'm not aware of such a language feature. But I'm curious, *if it did exist*, what would you use it for?

Comment: Checking that your variable has a size of 2 and is "thus" 16 bits, still doesn't mean anything in C. Is it a short, an unsigned short, a (very short) string, a struct of 2 chars?

Comment: @Alexander In, say, Python, you can use check whether a value is an integer or float, and pass it through a different control flow depending on the result. Although I can't really think of a real good reason for that anyway. Perhaps the OP is thinking along those lines.

Comment: @9769953 Even in Python, where that's *possible*, doing explicit type-checks like is very suspicious (and discouraged), because it totally undermines the whole "point" of object orientation (polymorphism and substitutability). "Although I can't really think of a real good reason for that anyway." Precisely, that's why I think it's so important to understand what OP is trying to achieve with this feature, if it hypothetically existed.

Comment: I may be over-reading the intention of the question, but if the goal is to take a particular action based on the type of a variable, you may want to look into the `_Generic` keyword added in C11. There's some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do the same for struct in C?

`sizeof(my_variable)` does the exact same thing for structs as for non-structs.

Specifically,

- `sizeof( my_variable ) == 2` doesn't mean the variable uses up 16 bit.

  It means that my_variable uses up 2 bytes. Even though a byte is usually 8 bits in size these days, that's not always the case. Historically, they have been as large as 32 bits!
- `sizeof( my_variable ) == 2` doesn't mean the variable can store 16-bit numbers.

  `sizeof` doesn't say anything about the type except for its size.

For example,

`sizeof( long )` `sizeof( float )` and `sizeof( struct { char a; int b; } )` could all return the same number.