# C - How to use macro to create specific pointer type?

Tags: c

I know macro can return value of custom type:

```
#define returnVal(type) ({ \
    type val;              \
    val;                   \
})
```

I am trying to create a macro which can return custom type pointer by input number. (So it can be dynamic)

```
// Pseudo code
#define returnPtr(number) ({              \
   // if number == 1, return int *val     \
   // if number == 2, return int **val    \
   // if number == 3, return int ***val   \
})
```

I tried some approaches but it doesn't work:

```
#define returnPtr(number) ({                             \
    type = number == 1 ? int * : number == 2 ? int **    \
                                             : int ***;  \
    type val;                                            \
    val;                                                 \
})
```

How to return custom type pointer by input number in a macro function?

Comment: You might be able to use [_Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11) for this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It feels like an XY Problem.  Macros are rarely a good answer to a problem.

Comment: If the purpose is to write bad and hard to read code, you are on the correct path.... If that isn't the purpose just drop the idea

Comment: Please note that `({` are so-called "expression statements", a gcc extension and not standard C.

Answer (score 2):

If the macro argument is just a literal `0`, `1`, etc., this can be done by pasting it (with `##`) to form a name (like `TYPE0`, `TYPE1`, etc.) that is defined as a macro to be replaced with a type name. The following code shows a way to do this. Note that writing code like this is generally bad practice absent compelling reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>    


#define TYPE1   int *
#define TYPE2   int **
#define TYPE3   int ***


#define Kludge(number)  (TYPE##number) {0}


#define Demo(number)                \
    _Generic(Kludge(number),        \
        int *:    "int *",          \
        int **:   "int **",         \
        int ***:  "int ***",        \
        default:  "something else")


int main(void)
{
    puts(Demo(1));
    puts(Demo(2));
    puts(Demo(3));
}
```

Output:

```
int *
int **
int ***
```