# How to make this dprint macro work for all types in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to improve upon a macro from the K&R C book.  It is used to print an expression and its value.

```
#define  dprint(expr)  printf(#expr " = %g\n", expr)
```

However, when I use it to print an `int`, it prints a very low number, such as "`4.023e-325`" regardless of the value of the `int`.

If I use the `%d` format, the correct value is printed.

How can I alter the function to print in the correct format depending on the type of "`expr`"?

Comment: `%g` probably requires a `float` or `double`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11

Answer (score 5):

You can use a type-generic macro:

```
#define dprint(expr) printf(#expr " = %" _Generic((expr), \
                 double: "g",  \
                 int: "d",     \
                 char *: "s",  \
                 long: "ld"    \
                 ) "\n", expr)
```

Comment: This solution requires C11 or later, but that is usually not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of the expression is a number simply cast it to double - but of course it will not be precise in some cases

```
#define  dprint(expr)  printf(#expr " = %g\n", (double)(expr))

int main(void)
{
    dprint(1);
    dprint(3*3);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qdb7hcssr